# Protecting sensitive data in cache

Tags: encryption, sensitive-data-exposure

I have a java application which is reading sensitive data from database (open symmetric key, read data from database) and storing it in-memory cache. I want to make sure that no one should able to dump this data to disk (say by crashing process).

- Is it possible?
- What all possible way could be to get this sensitive data?

If application is already running then even the user who is running the application should not be able to dump data (without modifying code of the application).

**Background:** Application will get password from some super user (say via web interface). This password is used to open symmetric key in database and decrypt data.

Comment: Can you use an HSM/Smartcard for this?

Comment: This question is on the line of my application now has the secret to unlock symmetric key. I want to make sure that memory dump of my application should not reveal this secret.